# How to fix canvas.clipPath crashes causing fatal 11 (SIGSEGV) error in android?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, gdi

I am trying to construct picture using Picture class in android.And when I call canvas.clipPath(path,Region.Op.REPLACE) is causing Fatal 11 (SIGSEGV) code1 (SEGV_MAPERR) error.Is there any way to fix it or any work arounds are there to solve it?

I tried disabling Hardware acceleration and it didn't worked.

Platform:
Android 4.2, 4.3, 4.4

Devices:
Nexus 7, Samsung Galaxy

Related links:
[SIGSEGV in Canvas.clipPath at the second clipPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194193/sigsegv-in-canvas-clippath-at-the-second-clippath)
[Canvas.clipPath(Path) not clipping as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672802/canvas-clippathpath-not-clipping-as-expected)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported

Comment: Are you using an emulator?

Comment: No I am running on devices only.